# AWS Glue autoscaling doesn't scale down

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-glue

We are running an AWS Glue job with autoscaling.
From the Glue monitoring view, we can see that `--enable-auto-scaling` is set to `true` and the `Number of workers` is set to 30.

This is the executors graph:
[image]

As you can see, the number of maximum needed executors is way lower than the active executors for a very long period of time, and AWS doesn't scale down the executors.

I couldn't find anything in the documentation that explains this behavior.

Can anyone explain it?